# Regex extract time from GMT string

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings such as

```
(GMT -4:00)Puerto Rico
(GMT -3:30)Newfoundland
(GMT -3:00)Asuncion
(GMT +2:00)Athens
```

How can I extraxt the time from those string?
This was my poor shot: `\([0-9](.*?)\)`
Result should look like this: `-4:00, -3:30, -3:00...`

I am very bad at this.

Comment: Maybe this will help you [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You may use a mere

```
[-+]\d+:\d+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b-%2b%5d%5cd%2b%3a%5cd%2b&i=%28GMT+-4%3a00%29Puerto+Rico%0d%0a%28GMT+-3%3a30%29Newfoundland%0d%0a%28GMT+-3%3a00%29Asuncion%0d%0a%28GMT+%2b2%3a00%29Athens)

**Details**:

- `[-+]` - matches `-` or `+`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

[image]

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"[-+]\d+:\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

A possible alternative [non-regex solution](http://ideone.com/iGrvQ6) to process each separate input:

```
var s = "(GMT -4:00)Puerto Rico";
var res = s.Split(new[] {" ", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I feel so bad because I have never been able to understand regex. It really is something I have been using for years and never could understand it. I can't combine the pattern in my head.
Huge thanks @Wiktor.

Comment: or .ElementAtOrDefault(1) instead of the skip